# How does GetStdHandle() knows what my process is?

Tags: c++, winapi

When I call `GetStdHandle()` (or some other function that does something with my process), for example:

```
HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

`GetStdHandle()` will return the `STDOUT` handle of my process, but how does this function knows what my process is, I mean I did not gave it the process id as a parameter.

Comment: Every process has a [PEB](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Process_Environment_Block) associated with it, basically the function just returns that value from the PEB.

Comment: The STDIN handle is a global variable of the calling process.  The function is simply returning the current value.  The value is established at process startup, unless your code calls `SetStdHandle()` to overwrite it.

Comment: Because the operating system know what process it's currently running, and it will [happily give you a handle to it if you ask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The documentation you linked to says: "The return value is a **pseudo handle** to the current process.A pseudo handle is a special constant, currently `(HANDLE)-1`".  So it is not actually returning a real handle to the calling process.  Just a fake value that signals lower-level APIs to resolve the actual process handle when needed.

Comment: ... but you can [turn it into a real handle easily enough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Windows there's Thread Environment Block per thread that stored into CPU segment like `fs` on x86 and `gs` on x64. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/thread-environment-block--debugging-notes-

Inside Thread Environment Block there's Process Environment Block, https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/inc/api/pebteb/teb/index.htm that stored `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETER`.

This is where they stored the Standard Handles, https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/inc/api/pebteb/rtl_user_process_parameters.htm?ts=0,159.

So `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` return `NtCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameter->StandardOutput` and so on.

Assembly on x64

```
%define NtCurrentPeb gs:[0x60]
%define ProcessParameter 32
%define StandardOutput 40

mov rax, NtCurrentPeb()
mov rax, ProcessParameter[rax]
mov rax, StandardOutput[rax]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's pretend that you needed to pass the process ID.  How would you go about doing that?

```
DWORD my_id = GetCurrentProcessId();
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, my_id);
```

Obviously, if we're going to call this more than once, we could save ourselves some duplication of effort, by putting it into a helper function:

```
HANDLE MyGetStdHandle(DWORD nStdHandle)
{
  DWORD my_id = GetCurrentProcessId();
  return GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, my_id);
}
```

But heck, lots of people are going to need this function.  Maybe we should put it into a library ... or an API ... in fact, let's just add it to the Windows API and call it GetStdHandle().

Which they did.

(OK, it doesn't really work that way, but I think it illustrates the point.  The Windows API *has* to know what process you are calling it from, or it wouldn't be able to do *anything*.)

Comment: But how does `GetCurrentProcessId()` knows what my process is? (maybe this function should have been in my question).

Comment: The actual implementation probably makes use of the PEB as per Jonathan's comment.  But in principle it doesn't need to.  Windows is in control of the CPU; at the start of the current timeslice, it decided that it would get the CPU to run the code from your program, and it has a record of that decision (as per Joachim's comment).

Comment: (For comparison, something like DOS, where the operating system *isn't* in control of the CPU when an application runs, is even simpler: there *is* only ever one standard output handle, because only one application can run at a time.  Which also means no process IDs.)